# Appending an Array to an Array of a different type

Tags: arrays, swift, oop, inheritance

I have 2 arrays of different types. One of which inherits some variables and extends them. And I want to append the array of the first one to the second one, but I get this error:

```
No exact matches in call to instance method 'append'
```

This is how the classes look like:

```swift
class FirstModel {
    let name: String
    let id: Int
}

class SecondModel: FirstModel {
    let number: Int
}
```

Here are the arrays:

```swift
var firstArray: [FirstModel] = []
var secondArray: [SecondModel] = []
```

And inside a view is a button that appends them (and here comes the error):

```swift
Button("Do something") {
    secondArray.append(contentsOf: firstArray)
}
```

[I've seen this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/no-exact-matches-in-call-to-instance-method-append/17397), but how would you decode an array in my situation to do the same?

Comment: You need to make them one somehow like via a protocol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, you can use a protocol to represent the common behavior of the two models.

```
import SwiftUI

struct FirstModel: Model {
    var number: Int
    let name: String
}

struct SecondModel: Model {
    var number: Int
}

protocol Model {
    var number: Int { get set }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var firstArray: [FirstModel] = []
    @State private var secondArray: [SecondModel] = []
    @State private var finalArray: [Model] = []
    
    init() {
        // if you want to initialize the finalArray with firstArray
        finalArray.append(contentsOf: firstArray)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Add") {
            finalArray.append(contentsOf: secondArray)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that not all `FirstModel`s are `SecondModel`s. Thus, it doesn't make sense to add `FirstModel`s to an array that can store only `SecondModel`s.

If you'd like `secondArray` to be able to store both `FirstModel`s and `SecondModel`s, then you should make its type be `[FirstModel]`. Then in your app you might write something like

```swift
ForEach(secondArray) { model in
    if let secondModel = model as? SecondModel {
        // This model is a `SecondModel`
    }
    else {
        // It's just a `FirstModel`
    }
}
```

An alternative solution is to keep `secondArray` as a `[SecondModel]` but to change the appending code to:

```swift
secondArray.append(contentsOf: firstArray.compactMap { $0 as? SecondModel })
```

This approach extracts from `firstArray` only the elements that are actually `SecondModel`s. Check out the documentation for `compactMap` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/compactmap(_:)).

I don't know which solution is best for you because it depends on what behavior you want, but I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is to add the elements of `secondArray` to the `firstArray` instead since `SecondModel` inherits from `FirstModel`

```
firstArray.append(contentsOf: secondArray)
```

or create a new array

```
let all = firstArray + secondArray
```

If it must be the `secondArray` that holds all elements then you need to change its definition to

```
var secondArray: [FirstModel] = []
```